# An immersive map is locally left invertible

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Question:

> Suppose that $m < n$, that $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^m$ and that $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is a $C^1$ function that has rank $m$ everywhere in $U$. Show that for every $x$ in $U$ there is a neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ and a $C^1$ function $\tilde f : V \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ that is a left inverse of $f$ in $V$ (that is, $\tilde f\circ  f$ is the identity on $V$).

I do not understand the last sentence of this question. What does it mean by identity on $V$? Shouldn't the domain of $\tilde f\circ f$ is at least in $\mathbb R^m$ instead of $V$ which is in $\mathbb R^n$? Which of the following two is correct, please?

1. $(\tilde f\circ f)(x^1,\cdots, x^m)=(x^1,\cdots, x^m)$; or
2. $(\tilde f\circ f)(x^1,\cdots, x^m)=(x^1,\cdots, x^m, 0, \cdots, 0)$.

In addition, I started with trying constant rank theorem, but it did not seem to work since rank theorem only change coordinates in $\mathbb R^m$ and $\mathbb R^n$ without connecting them. Any hint, please?

Comment: It's a typo. It should be $U$. What this really says is that an immersion is locally invertible. Are you familiar with tubular neighbourhoods? By the way, it strikes me as more differential topology than differential geometry...

Comment: @tomasz So you mean the first item in my list is the right interpretation?

Comment: Yes. And disregard the question about tubular neighbourhoods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: consider the composition of $f$ with the projection onto the tangent space at $f(x)$ (considered as an $m$-dimensional affine subspace of ${\bf R}^n$).

Comment: The reason why $f$ only has left inverse instead of both left and right inverses is that its domain doesn't have enough dimensions. Right?

Comment: Yes. The range of $f$ is $m$-dimensional, so it can't cover an open set in an $n$-dimensional space. Note that this generalizes immediately to maps between arbitrary manifolds of suitable dimensions (by considering local charts).

Comment: So by local immersion theorem, there exist some bases such that $f(x^1, \cdots, x^m)=(x^1, \cdots, x^m, 0, \cdots, 0)\in \mathbb R^n$. Then I can simply project $(x^1, \cdots, x^m, 0, \cdots, 0)$ onto $\mathbb R^m$ as $(x^1, \cdots, x^m)$. Right? And this projection is unique. Right?

Comment: Well, yes, if you use that, then this is rather trivial, I kind of thought this is exactly what you're supposed to prove here. I'm not sure what you mean by that the projection is unique, though. You can certainly compose it with e.g. any general linear map, getting a different “projection”.